# C# Azure MediaServices uploading file throws an error

Tags: c#, windows, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-media-services

I'm using an MVC4 test project to try to upload a file to the Azure Media Services.

I can create my CloudMediaContext fine. I can also create an IAsset and within that, an IAssetFile.
**However, when I try to upload a new file to it, I get following exception:**

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=3.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

I'm not sure whether the error lies within MVC4 for not being able to upload a file from its own directoy?
According to the error, I have some missing references or assemblies, but the only thing I've added is the NuGet package to Azure.MediaServices, which installed the Azure MediaServices .NET SDK...

**This is the HomeController code for Upload:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    string localStorage = Server.MapPath("~/UploadedMedia");
    string uploadedFileName = file.FileName;
    if (!Directory.Exists(localStorage))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(localStorage);
    file.SaveAs(string.Format(@"{1}\{0}", file.FileName, localStorage));
    _mediaServicesContext = new MediaServicesContext();
    _mediaServicesContext.UploadFile(string.Format(@"{1}\{0}", file.FileName, localStorage));

    return View(new UploadModel() { FileName = uploadedFileName, Post = true, Result = true });
}
```

**And this is my MediaServices class (doing the work)**

```
public class MediaServicesContext
{
    #region ATTRIBUTES
    private const string MEDIACONTEXTNAMEKEY = "MediaServiceAccountName";
    private const string MEDIACONTEXTPASSKEY = "MediaServiceAccountAccessKey";
    private const string MEDIASTORAGENAMEKEY = "StorageAccountName";
    private const string MEDIASTORAGEPASSKEY = "StorageAccountAccessKey";

    private readonly CloudMediaContext _mediaContext;
    #endregion

    #region CTORS
    public MediaServicesContext()
    {
        _mediaContext = new CloudMediaContext(accountName: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[MEDIACONTEXTNAMEKEY],
                                                accountKey: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[MEDIACONTEXTPASSKEY]);
    }
    #endregion

    #region PROPERTIES
    public CloudMediaContext MediaContext
    {
        get { return _mediaContext; }
    }
    #endregion

    #region METHODS
    public void UploadFile(string path)
    {
        // Create a .NET console app
        // Set the project properties to use the full .NET Framework (not Client Profile)
        // With NuGet Package Manager, install windowsazure.mediaservices
        // add: using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client;
        var uploadFilePath = path;
        var context = _mediaContext;
        var uploadAsset = context.Assets.Create(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(uploadFilePath), AssetCreationOptions.None);
        var assetFile = uploadAsset.AssetFiles.Create(Path.GetFileName(uploadFilePath));
        assetFile.Upload(uploadFilePath);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, following solved my issue.

In the NuGet PackageManager Console, I typed following:

```
PM> Install-Package WindowsAzure.Storage
```

This seems to have updated the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage dependency and allows my program to work properly.
Very weird, Microsoft.